# Destruction of class with condition variable in wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, race-condition

My problem is as follows:

I have a thread that waits for a condition variable. And I need to destroy this thread. It seems simple enough to do:

```
~myclass()
{
    myConditionVariable.notifyAll();
    myThread.join();
}
```

However the problem doing this, is that the thread running the destructor may get halted, allowing for new wait calls on the condition variable.

On top of I have got a member function with a wait call on the condition variable in it. Say:

```
myMemberFunction()
{
    myConditionVariable.wait(myLock);
}
```

This may be called from the outside on a number of threads. How do I make sure all these calls are wrapped up before the actual destruction.

**Edit:**

For completity a sample class:

```
Myclass()
{
public:
    std::mutex waitMutex;

    std::condition_variable waitConditionVariable;

    //n.b. this function can be called from multiple threads;
    void wait()
    {
        std::condition_variable(wait);
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
         //what should i do here?
    }

};
```

Comment: Is `myConditionVariable` a class member or a global variable?

Comment: The short answer is, don't architect this way. Deadlock is likely. (I've just fixed one in my code base.) The longer answer is: what's happening in the main event loop? If it is doing notifies and won't stop, then eventually this will get awakened.

Comment: @Nathan myConditionVariable

Comment: @AndrewLazarus How should I code condition variables then if I may ask?

Comment: I was a little flip. But if you have two condition variables, and both can be in wait state, that's an obvious problem. Can you have both CVs happening on a thread other than the object-creation?

Comment: @ I only have one condition variable. But multiple threads may wait on this variable. I'll provide an example class to clarify things:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we are calling `~myclass` from the master thread (call it Thread A), you can check whether it is needed to be stopped in the slave thread (call it Thread B):

And we have an `Atomic<bool>` variable named `Stop` which is accessible from both Threads.

In the thread A:

```
~myclass()
{
    Stop = true;   
    myConditionVariable.notifyAll();
    myThread.join();
}
```

In the thread B:

```
myConditionVariable.wait(myMutexLock, [&] return Stop || haveWorkToDo(); );
if (Stop)
   // Terminate Thread
// continue to work
```

Comment: The problem here is that the calls to the function containing the wait can come from the outside. Is it possible to force those to exit the function? Or is it bad design to allow functions to do that?

Comment: I don't think it is an ever-possible task to ask threads to terminate from outside in C/C++. They might blocks somewhere (notably in some syscalls). In other words, those threads won't quit themselves until they learn to `yield` and then quit or get killed by the system via `pthread_kill` or `TerminateThread` (well, that could become even worse).

Comment: Well the threads don't have to terminate. They just have to leave the function in the current object. Probably returning a message the request failed because the object got destructed.

Comment: Edited: I am not sure, but maybe you can use a semaphore when entering and leaving the object method. Increment it when entering and decrement it when leaving, and check atomic Stop flag before executing any actual code in the object method. In the thread A, waits the semaphore to count zero and then join other working threads.

Comment: Edit2: semaphore implies the use of lock to protect it, which is not good enough. It seems using `Atomic<int>` is more suitable here (call `std::atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&Count, 1, memory_order_acquire)` when entering any object method and call `std::atomic_fetch_sub_explicit(&Count, 1, memory_order_release)` when leaving it). But the con of this method is that in the thread A you need do a while loop to check the value of `Count` and wait it to zero manually.

Comment: `Stop = true;` should be called with the mutex lock holed, the mutex is the same one used in the condition variable.

Comment: Isn't is unsafe to use members in destructor?